# w00t! I've got a close hammer!

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

The other day, I saw an off-topic post and voted to close it, even though I'm still at 101 rep on the main site. Didn't think much of it until today when I was on another public beta SE site where I also had 101 rep and was unable to vote to close a question.

If you compare the [faq on mechanics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) with [the one here](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), you'll see the values are different. I assume it's a bug, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm going to miss my close hammer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have bumped the privs up for public beta levels.

Answer (score 2):

Now you see it, now you don't! (:

Good catch.  The privileges were indeed still on private beta levels.  These levels are for the first week of a new site when nobody has any rep.  Since Homebrewing was an old SE 1.0 import, a few things at the beginning were fudged a bit, and this step got missed.

(You can [compare the different rep levels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) if you want...)

The privileges have been adjusted to the proper levels as shown in the [faq](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: yup... no more close hammer. Thanks! `:)` It still looks like the [faq](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/faq) is incorrect to me, though, even with a hard-refresh using Ctrl-F5.